# JavaScript anonymous function parameters and calling arrangement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anonymous-function

In a tutorial related to React, which I am watching on YouTube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3KeJRKYpj8

there was a piece of code that had the following (minute 13:40 in the video)

```
    const setCounterWithValue = (value) => {
        setCounter(value)
    }
```

this function gets called from a button component in the following code:

```
<button onClick={() => setCounterWithValue(counter -1)}
```

The video tutorial suggested a way to shorten this function call and make it simpler.
So what he did was modifying the code to be as follows (minute 14:30 in the video):

```
const setCounterWithValue = value => () => {
    setCounter(value)
}
```

which meant the button component became as follows:

```
<button onClick={setCounterWithValue(counter -1)}
```

So my problem here is that I was expecting the setCounterWithValue to be structured as the following:

```
const setCounterWithValue = () => (value) => {
    setCounter(value)
}
```

so empty () then pass value which triggers the setCounter.
I would like to have some deep explanation and some resources (like articles and videos) that explain this in further details.

Comment: How would you pass `counter - 1` to a function that takes no parameters like your expectation is? You are saying you expect the function to take no parameters and return a function that takes a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that its simpler... What they are doing is called currying. Its a shorthand way to create a function that returns a function. So a longhand form would look like this:

```js
const setCounterWithValue = (value) => {
  return function () {
    setCounter(value)
  }
}
```

Its probably easier to understand why the parameters go where they do when written in this form. When you call it inline you're calling the outer function `<button onClick={setCounterWithValue(counter -1)} />`. It then returns the a function that should be called when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

What they're doing there is called [currying](https://dev.to/bettercodingacademy/functional-programming-all-you-need-to-know-about-currying-5k7). In other words, it's a function that returns another function. Instead of firing it outright, they're taking the value of the first function's argument and utilizing it in the second function that is fired from the the click event. In this particular case I don't see it being any *simpler* as you're getting the same exact outcome but in this case your original function is just fired in the second function body. Nevertheless, more info on currying can be found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/).

Answer (score 1):

Calling the "simpler" function with `setCounterWithValue(counter - 1)` will return a function that, when executed, will pass through the counter value provided. The concept for this is called currying through the use of a closure. The function you "expected" wouldn't make much sense because you'd be calling it with a value, but that value never gets captured, so the function it returns is expecting a value parameter, which is not passed, it gets lost.

Here's the two examples:

Example 1:

```
const setCounterWithValue = value => () => {
    setCounter(value)
}
```

When called with `setCounterWithValue(42)`, it will return the following:

```
() => { setCounter(42) }
```

Example 2:

As opposed to what you said you expected, which would end up like the following:

```
const setCounterWithValue = () => (value) => {
    setCounter(value)
}
```

Called with `setCounterWithValue(42)` would return the following:

```
(value) => { setCounter(value) }
```

Notice how the function being returned still expects a value to be provided. This is the difference between the two examples and why Example 1 would work, while this one wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of currying, which you can use as an introduction to Higher Order Functions which are very common in the React ecosystem.

To break down what happens in this case and why your assumption on how the function should look is wrong, you first have to understand what JavaScript closures are.

Let's say we have this piece of code:

```
function foo() {
    var bar = 5;
    return function baz() {
        console.log(bar);
    }
}

foo();  // Returns a function. Nothing happens
foo()(); // The returned function is executed. Prints 5
```

Here we take advantage of a closure that is created on line 3. The function `baz` that we return from `foo` captures the context of its definition site (definition site = where the function is defined = in this case the `foo` function). So `baz` can be called from anywhere and still have access to the place in memory that `bar` points to.

The first invocation does nothing since the returned function is not called. 
The second invocation calls the returned function therefore printing the number 5 to the console.

In order to understand your example snippet you can be more explicit in the function definition:

This:

```
const setCounterWithValue = value => () => {
    setCounter(value)
}
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
function setCounterWithValue(value) {
   return function() {
      setCounter(value)
    }
}
```

The instructor in the video just takes advantage of the [implicit return feature of arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

The code snippet just above will have the same result when used with your code. Hopefully, written like this, it makes more sense to you why there is no need for the anonymous function to have a `value` argument. It can access it via a closure.

As to why currying and high order functions are preferred by some JavaScript developers, the answer is way too long and opinionated, so I suggest you study the subject a bit more. A very interesting article can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

A bit harder to read but with a bunch of useful theory: https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to understand using function declaration instead of arrow functions. The tutorial suggests you refactor the function into a function factory:

```
function setCounterWithValue (value) {
    return function () {
        setCounter(value);
    }
}
```

This means that calling the function above will return a function that requires no arguments:

```
let f = setCounterWithValue(1);
f(); // this sets counter to 1
```

Your suggested function instead returns a function that requires an argument:

```
function setCounterWithValue () {
    return function (value) {
        setCounter(value);
    }
}
```

This means to set the value you will have to pass an argument:

```
let f = setCounterWithValue();
f(1); // set value to 1
```

The problem the refactor is trying to solve is that onclick functions are **always** called with an event object as the argument. When the button is clicked, the browser will call your function as:

```
setCounterWithValue(event);
```

You have no control over this. It is impossible to force the browser to call it any other way. Thus, ideally you want to pass into the onclick handler a function that ignores the `event` argument:

```
function setCounterWithValue (value) {
    return function () {
        setCounter(value);
    }
}

let f = setCounterWithValue(counter -1); // this returns a function
                                         // that ignores arguments

return <button onClick={f} />
```

most people would avoid using a temporary variable so:

```
<button onClick={setCounterWithValue(counter -1)} />
```

On the other hand, if you use your suggestion you would need to do:

```
{/* wrap in an anonymous function to ignore the event */}
<button onClick={() => setCounterWithValue(counter -1)} />
```